# Не отрабатывает фильтр html в Angular

Tags: php, angularjs

```
angular.module("Angular", [])
.controller("AngularCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.setPhone = function(phone, user_phone) {
    return phone ? "<input type='text' id='phone' value='" + user_phone + "'>" : user_phone;
};
})
.filter('html', function($sce) {
return function(val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
};
});
```

Выше, собственно, код; ниже - html:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    {{setPhone(phone, '<?= $user['phone'] ?>') | html}}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="phone">
    </div>
</div>
```

Не могу понять, почему не отрабатывает фильтр (как метод тоже не работает, если сделать альтернативный, с той же функцией).

Comment: какое значение вместо _<?= $user['phone'] ?>_ приходит?

Comment: Вначале {{setPhone(phone, +7-(999)-999-99-99) | html}} (номер, правда, обычный, немного другой), а когда нажимаешься checkbox, меняется на <input type='text' id='phone' value='-1902'>

Comment: Добавил в кавычки, и номер начал выводиться. Но фильтр html не действует, не удается вывести html не в виде тега.

Comment: а что должен делать фильтр?

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko, очевидно выводить html :)

Comment: не очевидно. У вас строка на входе уже html.

Comment: @AlexeyProkopenko, и что мешает вывести ее как html? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите, что бы у вас строка выводилась как html, вам нужно использовать директиву **ng-bind-html**. Через фигурные скобки строка не будет рендериться.

```js
angular.module("MyApp", [])
  .controller("AngularCtrl", function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.setPhone = function(phone, user_phone) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(phone ? "<input type='text' id='phone' value='" + user_phone + "'>" : user_phone);

    };
    $scope.phone = true;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="AngularCtrl">
    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-bind-html="setPhone(phone,'+7-(999)-999-99-99')">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="phone">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что должен демонстрировать данный пример?

Comment: Вот, все верно, спасибо!